# Is "I turned on and off the computer" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Sounds wrong to me, and I would say, "I turned the computer off, and then on again", but I was wondering if both forms are acceptable.

Comment: Weird. It sound "wrong" to me too, but I see no need to introduce additional words into the resequenced version to make it "natural". To me, there's nothing at all even "odd" about *"I turned the computer on and off"*. But I have no idea why I think you can't *turn on and off a computer*, whereas you can [*step on and off the scales*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22step+on+and+off+the+scales%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (or *walk up and down the road*, etc., etc.).

Comment: add an 'again' and it will sound pretty good: "I turned the computer on and off again."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FumbleFingers' comment points to what's going on here:

> ... you can't *turn on and off a computer*, whereas you can *step on and off the scales* (or *walk up and down the road*, etc., etc.)

In *step on and off the scales* both *on* and *off* act as prepositions, taking *scales* as their respective objects, and conjoining the two prepositions implies an ellipsis of two conjoined preposition phrases: *on the scales and off the scales*.  This is consonant with how we express the  result of each action:

> I step on the scales. > I am now on the scales.
>   I step off the scales. > I am now off the scales.

But in *turned on* (or *off*) the computer*, *on* (or *off*) does not act as a preposition but as an adjective designating a state which you cause the computer to assume. Note that with *turn*, unlike with *step*, *on* (or *off*) can be posed after the object:

> I turned on the computer = I turned the computer on > The computer is now on.

The preposition phrases implicit in the conjunct preposed prepositions are not valid. Consequently we must postpose the conjunction:

> I turned the computer on and off.

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that? Another example of the "multiple adjectival words" construction would be *"I turned the volume up and down"*, where you can't say *"I turned up and down the volume"* (but you *can* say *"I looked up and down the street"*, and at a pinch you can say *"I looked her up and down"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers And to draw the line even more sharply: *I turned it on and off its head* works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This question and the answers it received constitute a very interesting case because OP wanted to know whether

> "I turned on and off the computer"

is ***grammatically correct?***,

when in fact all the answers have tried to explain why it is **not preferable**, while apparently forgetting to make it clear whether it is really "grammatically wrong" or just an awkward construction.

Looking at the sentence I see a subject-verb-object sequence as in

> I (subject) turned on and off (verb + [adverbs](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/off_1)) the computer (object.)

Meaning: I *turned on* and *turned off* the computer.

I agree that it's not ideally structured -- the better construction would be

> I turned the computer on and off

(repeatedly doing which, by the way, is not recommended by either software or hardware engineers) -- but I see nothing to indicate it is ***grammatically wrong***; it only seems awkward: other examples are

> he continuously pressed in and out the master switch.
>
> they kept pushing up and down the stairs the rubber sledge.
>
> she called up, greeted and asked again and again the receptionist whether the tickets were ready [deliberately provocative example]

In each case the sentence construction is admittedly awkward, but not  necessarily 'grammatically wrong', methinks; expert grammarians can correct me if I am mistaken in this interpretation, and explain why OP's sentence would be "grammatically wrong" while quoting the relevant rule in an answer or comments.

Note 2: can somebody clarify what is the definition/ interpretation (widely accepted by standard resources and grammarians) of the oft-repeated and controversial term "grammatically correct", especially as it applies to this question raised by OP?

Comment: The answer by @Stoney clearly explains why the sentence is not grammatical.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're mixing two questions. *Turning the computer off and on* is something you can only do when it is on to start with. *I flicked the light switch on and off* (to test the power, because it started in the 'off' position) is a perfectly normal phrase, but does not denote the same process as *turning the light off and on* (to give the starter a better chance), though that is equally normal.

And whether you insert *again* in the phrase is largely a matter of choice. It may be that 'flicking the switch on and off' is a single action ending in the off position, where 'flicking it on and off' is more aimless; but equally that may be more precise than most people's language actually is.